# Get Index of a Object into mapped array React JS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, indexing, undefined

I hope you're doing well :)

Here my issue :

I'm mapping the  component and I would to change its status when I click on it (isActive : boolean).
But I'm struggling to catch the  **index**. When I try TabButtons[0].isActive, it's working for this element. But when I'm less specific (TabButtons[index].isActive, the console return "undefined".
What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you so much guys !

[image]

Comment: you have to pass the index like: `<TabButtonItem ... HandleButtonState(index) />`

Comment: Please do not post code as image. Please amend your question to include the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the index to `handleButtonState`

`<TabButtonItem onClick={()=> handleButtonState(index)}>`